# Matlab Image Restoration using Wiener filter

Tags: matlab

I have an image which was blurred via a horizontal motion blur.
I have to restore it using the wiener filter.
I did the following:

```
I = im2double(imread('blurred image.tif')); % Load image
LEN = 50; 
THETA = 0; 
noise_var = 0.001;
est_nsr = noise_var /var(I(:)); 
PSF = fspecial('motion',LEN,THETA);
wnr = deconvwnr(I,PSF, est_nsr);
```

When I look at the resotred image, it seems as if there are vertical lines that ruin the image quality, plus, there is quite a lot of noise. 
I tried playing with the parameters but that's the best I could get.
Am I maybe doing this wrong?

Comment: No that sounds about right.  It is almost impossible to fully reconstruct the original image given motion blur.  You will certainly make out some of the original structure.  Take a look at Slide #11 from these lecture slides: http://eeweb.poly.edu/~yao/EL5123/lecture13_ImageRestoration.pdf - You can see that even though they use the Wiener filter to reconstruct the image from motion blur, they don't fully restore the image back to its original state.... motion blur just flat out sucks!